# How to import old log files to graylog as input?

Tags: apache, logging, graylog

I am able to to setup [graylog-server](https://www.graylog.org/) and graylog-web and able to setup input for generated log of apache2, tomcat and other applications with the help of [graylog-collector](https://github.com/Graylog2/collector)
e.g.

```
apache-access {
    type = "file"
    path = "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
    outputs = "gelf-tcp,console"
  }
tomcat-debug {
    type = "file"
    path = "/home/alok/packages/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/logs/mydomain.debug.log"
    outputs = "gelf-tcp,console"
  }
```

How to see log from old log files in graylog? I tried to setup graylog-collector for old log file, graylog is listening to it but not showing content of log file. if someone know the way to achieve this please share

Answer (score 11):

I am able to see my old log files (.log file) in graylog-web with help of [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

I just installed logstash and created a simple logstash configuration file having content

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/alok/Downloads/old_apache_access.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

#filter {
#    add filter according to need
#}

output {
  gelf {
    host => "10.149.235.66"
 }
}
```

`path` is path for my old log file that I want to import to graylog.
`start_position` tell logstash from where log lines to be read.
`gelf` to output logs in graylog's format.
`host` is address of graylog server.

now I can run logstash to read log file by running command.
`$/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-simple.conf`

Now I will add input in graylog for receiving logs from logstash. for that in main menu goto System >> Inputs

[image]

Then choose `GELF UDP` and lauch this newly selected input and give title to this and finally click on launch button.

[image]

Now one can see newly created input and click on Show received messages to see logs